# How to find out which row to delete in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parent

I want to delete a row in my table when the delete button is pushed. At the same time I want that item to be deleted from the array too.

I've used `this.parentNode` but it finds the `td` and not the `tr`. Have a look:

```
function deleteItem() {
    var tr = this.parentNode;
    shoppingCartTable.removeChild(tr);

}
```

I create the `shopping_cart` array when the page is loaded, making it empty. Items is added with this function:

```
    function addToCart() {
    // get which product that have been added
    var addedProduct = gallery[this.id]; 
    // push it in the array
    shopping_cart.push(addedProduct);

    // set the button to display none
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.display = "none";

    // get the single_item page 
    var single_item_page = document.getElementById("single_item");

    // create a p element and append to single_item
    var added = document.createElement("p");
    added.className = "addedProduct";
    added.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addedProduct.title + " has been added to your shopping cart "));
    single_item_page.appendChild(added);

    // add a number showing how many products your shopping bag have 
    shoppingCartLink.innerHTML =""; 
    shoppingCartLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Shopping Bag(" + shopping_cart.length + ")"));
    // call cartLink and updateCart
    updateCart();

}
```

So how do I delete the row that have been clicked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the row, you want the parent of the td (parent of the parent):

```
var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
```

To Delete from the array.

First, add the attribute "data-id" to the "tr" that you will later delete, so that it looks something like:

```
<tr data-id="12">....
</tr>
```

Then when you delete your tr:

function deleteItem() {
    var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var id = tr.getAttribute('data-id');
    shoppingCartTable.removeChild(tr);
    for (var i = 0; i < shopping_cart.length; i++) {
      if (shopping_cart[i] && shopping_cart[i].id == id) {
        shopping_cart.splice(i, 1);
        return;
      }
    }
}

Comment: Love when things are simple. Do you have any idea on how to delete the item from the array?

Comment: That's where it gets interesting. You can use one of a billion libraries to help you with databinding. I personally recommend Angularjs, but all of them take time to learn, but are worth it. For a "quick" solution, I would add the products "id" to the element using the attribute data-id. Then you would iterate through the array and look for a product with that id and then use `shopping_cart.splice(index, 1)`.